# How to dynamically change the value of a text label in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to make a guitar tuner with Python.

I have a complete function which is working fine in terminal, but can't get it work in tkinter, the text label value doesn't update.

Please let me know if there is a way to achieve this without recreating a class.
I've tried in several places to declare the window and the variable but can't get it work returns error;

```
(RuntimeError: main thread is not in main loop).
```

```
'''
Guitar tuner script based on the Harmonic Product Spectrum (HPS)

MIT License
Copyright (c) 2021 chciken
'''

import copy
import os
import numpy as np
import scipy.fftpack
import sounddevice as sd
import time
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk




# General settings that can be changed by the user
SAMPLE_FREQ = 48000 # sample frequency in Hz
WINDOW_SIZE = 48000 # window size of the DFT in samples
WINDOW_STEP = 12000 # step size of window
NUM_HPS = 5 # max number of harmonic product spectrums
POWER_THRESH = 1e-6 # tuning is activated if the signal power exceeds this threshold
CONCERT_PITCH = 440 # defining a1
WHITE_NOISE_THRESH = 0.2 # everything under WHITE_NOISE_THRESH*avg_energy_per_freq is cut off

WINDOW_T_LEN = WINDOW_SIZE / SAMPLE_FREQ # length of the window in seconds
SAMPLE_T_LENGTH = 1 / SAMPLE_FREQ # length between two samples in seconds
DELTA_FREQ = SAMPLE_FREQ / WINDOW_SIZE # frequency step width of the interpolated DFT
OCTAVE_BANDS = [50, 100, 200, 400, 800, 1600, 3200, 6400, 12800, 25600]

ALL_NOTES = ["A","A#","B","C","C#","D","D#","E","F","F#","G","G#"]


def find_closest_note(pitch):
  
  """
  This function finds the closest note for a given pitch
  Parameters:
    pitch (float): pitch given in hertz
  Returns:
    closest_note (str): e.g. a, g#, ..
    closest_pitch (float): pitch of the closest note in hertz
  """
  i = int(np.round(np.log2(pitch/CONCERT_PITCH)*12))
 
  closest_note = ALL_NOTES[i%12] + str(4 + (i + 9) // 12)
  closest_pitch = CONCERT_PITCH*2**(i/12)
 
  return closest_note, closest_pitch
   

HANN_WINDOW = np.hanning(WINDOW_SIZE)


def callback(indata, frames, time, status):
  """
  Callback function of the InputStream method.
  That's where the magic happens ;)
  """
     
  # define static variables
  if not hasattr(callback, "window_samples"):
    callback.window_samples = [0 for _ in range(WINDOW_SIZE)]
  if not hasattr(callback, "noteBuffer"):
    callback.noteBuffer = ["1","2"]

  if status:
    print(status)
    return
  
  if any(indata):
    callback.window_samples = np.concatenate((callback.window_samples, indata[:, 0])) # append new samples
    callback.window_samples = callback.window_samples[len(indata[:, 0]):] # remove old samples

    # skip if signal power is too low
    signal_power = (np.linalg.norm(callback.window_samples, ord=2)**2) / len(callback.window_samples)
    if signal_power < POWER_THRESH:
      os.system('cls' if os.name=='nt' else 'clear')
      print("Closest note: ...")
      return
    
    # avoid spectral leakage by multiplying the signal with a hann window
    hann_samples = callback.window_samples * HANN_WINDOW
    magnitude_spec = abs(scipy.fftpack.fft(hann_samples)[:len(hann_samples)//2])

    # supress mains hum, set everything below 62Hz to zero
    for i in range(int(62/DELTA_FREQ)):
      magnitude_spec[i] = 0

    # calculate average energy per frequency for the octave bands
    # and suppress everything below it
    for j in range(len(OCTAVE_BANDS)-1):
      ind_start = int(OCTAVE_BANDS[j]/DELTA_FREQ)
      ind_end = int(OCTAVE_BANDS[j+1]/DELTA_FREQ)
      ind_end = ind_end if len(magnitude_spec) > ind_end else len(magnitude_spec)
      avg_energy_per_freq = (np.linalg.norm(magnitude_spec[ind_start:ind_end], ord=2)**2) / (ind_end-ind_start)
      avg_energy_per_freq = avg_energy_per_freq**0.5
      for i in range(ind_start, ind_end):
        magnitude_spec[i] = magnitude_spec[i] if magnitude_spec[i] > WHITE_NOISE_THRESH*avg_energy_per_freq else 0

    # interpolate spectrum
    mag_spec_ipol = np.interp(np.arange(0, len(magnitude_spec), 1/NUM_HPS), np.arange(0, len(magnitude_spec)),
                              magnitude_spec)
    mag_spec_ipol = mag_spec_ipol / np.linalg.norm(mag_spec_ipol, ord=2) #normalize it

    hps_spec = copy.deepcopy(mag_spec_ipol)

    # calculate the HPS
    
    for i in range(NUM_HPS):
      tmp_hps_spec = np.multiply(hps_spec[:int(np.ceil(len(mag_spec_ipol)/(i+1)))], mag_spec_ipol[::(i+1)])
      
      if not any(tmp_hps_spec):
        break
      hps_spec = tmp_hps_spec
    
    max_ind = np.argmax(hps_spec)
    max_freq = max_ind * (SAMPLE_FREQ/WINDOW_SIZE) / NUM_HPS
    closest_note, closest_pitch = find_closest_note(max_freq)
    max_freq = round(max_freq, 1)
    closest_pitch = round(closest_pitch, 1)
    
 
     
   
   
    
    callback.noteBuffer.insert(0, closest_note) # note that this is a ringbuffer
    callback.noteBuffer.pop()
     
    os.system('cls' if os.name=='nt' else 'clear')
    
    

    
  if callback.noteBuffer.count(callback.noteBuffer[0]) == len(callback.noteBuffer):
    print(f"Closest note: {closest_note} {max_freq}/{closest_pitch}")
    
    fenetre=Tk()  
    l = Label(fenetre, text=f"{closest_note} {max_freq}/{closest_pitch}")    
    l.pack()   
    fenetre.mainloop()

    
    
  else:
    
    print("continue...")     
  
  
  
  
try:
    print("Starting HPS guitar tuner...")
    with sd.InputStream(channels=1, callback=callback, blocksize=WINDOW_STEP, samplerate=SAMPLE_FREQ):
      while True:
              
        time.sleep(0.5)
          
except Exception as exc:
  print(str(exc))
```

For the moment the window appears with the good value, but instead of updating the existing window it creates a new window each time the value updates.
I only need to change the label text value.

Comment: This is way too much code, how are we supposed to find the code that's trying to change the label? Please post a [mre].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As somebody already mentioned above, it is a lot of code and I am not sure, this will solve your problem, but I will give it a try:

If you want to dynamically change the value of a text label in tkinter here are a few things that may help you:

```
fenetre = Tk()
```

creates a tkinter window, you then have to run:

```
fenetre.mainloop()
```

to run your main window in a loop so it will always be updated.
Optimally this should not happen in a loop, but it may be possible.
Either way, what you can do to change the value of a text label is quite simple:

First you should define your label, possibly without any text, and then change the text whenever necessary. The full code may look like this:

```
from tkinter import *

fenetre = Tk()

your_label = Label(fenetre, text=None)
your_label.pack()
# This is just a basic label without any text, but:

def change_label_text(new_text):
    your_label.configure(text=new_text)
# This function changes the text of your label when you call it to whatever you put into the function 
# (A way of updating the value of a text label in tkinter)

# Finally finish the loop
fenetre.mainloop()
```

I hope this helps you out, if this doesnt answer your question or you have any further questions, please let me know.

Comment: thanks for your reply the configure option do the trick... thanks a lot

Comment: If it solved your problem, you can accept the answer and the problem will be closed and is not unanswered anymore...